# Proof Verification: Prove a nonzero, proper, prime ideal in a PID is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am going through the 'Algebraic Preliminaries' section from *Algebraic Curves* by William Fulton. I just want to make sure my algebra is not too rusty.

I saw a proof here (https://yutsumura.com/in-a-principal-ideal-domain-pid-a-prime-ideal-is-a-maximal-ideal/) but I want to check if mine also works. The main fact I'm making is every irreducible generates a principal ideal (perhaps this is wrong? It just seems obvious to me, and I didn't bother proving it independent yet).

Question: Let P be a nonzero, proper, prime ideal in R, where R is a PID. Show P is maximal.

Proof attempt: I shall perform proof by contradiction. Suppose P is not maximal. Then P $\subset$ *I* $\subset$ R, for some principal ideal *I*.

Let *h* be some element in R. If *h* is irreducible, it is contained in some principal ideal, and thus is also contained in *I* insofar as *I* is defined to be maximal.

If *h* is not irreducible, it can be expressed as a product of irreducibles (with will be unique up to ordering since a PID is also a UFD). Since, the ideals generated by each of these irreducibles are within I, each of these irreducibles are also within *I*, and thus can be expressed as a power of the irreducible generating *I*, *h* is also within I.

Such an argument can be used to place any element from *R* into *I*. Thus, *R* $\subset$ *I*. Obviously, *I* $\subset$ *R*, and so we have equality. In particular, P is maximal.

--

Thank you for your help!